# Aptitude - remove all packages in X11 category, except for dependencies of a specific package

Tags: package-management, aptitude

I would like to remove most of the packages in the X11 category from my system. However some of those packages are depended on by the 'beaglebone' package. How could I ask aptitude to remove everything in the X11 category, with the exception of the packages depended on by 'beaglebone'?

You can see below that it recommends 'beaglebone' as one of the packages that should be uninstalled at the risk of being broken.

[image: Aptitude recommended removal. Beaglebone is included.]

How can I make sure that this package and its dependencies are retained after the removal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
aptitude remove '~sX11 ! ~Rbeaglebone'
```

However in this kind of situation (there are a *lot* of things that depend on X11!), I recommend using the interactive resolver. To do this add the `--schedule-only` option to the above and run `aptitude` again without arguments .You may also have to add `-o Aptitude::Auto-Fix-Broken=false` to one or both commands (if it is not already in your settings), but I don't think you need it as as far as I can see the automatic resolution only happens when you press <kbd>g</kbd> in the interface.

Once you have the ncurses interface running, press <kbd>e</kbd> to examine the first solution and look at the additional removals. If you see any you don't want, use the arrow keys to select it and press <kbd>r</kbd> to reject the action. Press <kbd>.</kbd> to load the next solution, it should now provide a solution that doesn't include any of your rejections. Repeat as necessary and press <kbd>!</kbd> to accept the solution and continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use one of the following methods to "exclude" the package "beaglebone" which should force any of its dependencies to remain.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold <package>
```

or

```
$ echo <package> hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

The first makes use of `apt-mark` and its `hold` feature.

```
   hold
        hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the 
        package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed. The 
        command is only a wrapper around dpkg --set-selections and the state 
        is therefore maintained by dpkg(1) and not affected by the --file 
        option.
```

The second makes use of `dpkg` to mark a package as on "hold".

```
   --set-selections
        Set package selections using file read from stdin. This file should 
        be in the format 'package state', where state is one of install, 
        hold,  deinstall  or purge. Blank lines and comment lines beginning 
        with '#' are also permitted.
```

Comment: That will prevent `beaglebone` and its dependencies from being uninstalled, but how do you then remove all the other X11 packages? I can't immediately call to mind a method that wouldn't either undo the hold and remove `beaglebone`, or simply do nothing because it isn't able to remove `beaglebone` or one of its dependencies.

Comment: @Gilles - this was worth a shot. Debian/Ubuntu packaging is still something I'm learning about.

Comment: @Gilles - are you positive that pinning beaglebone in this way will not allow for other X11 packages that it isn't dependent on from being installed? I would still encourage the OP to try this just for the sake of seeing if it works.

Comment: @Gilles, putting a hold on `beaglebone` is a valid approach since it is not in the X11 section (actually there is no `beaglebone` package in Debian, but since this is a dev board I doubt the package belongs in X11). What is removing the package is the automatic resolver which should happily remove everything else without breaking the hold.